# MS Graph API endpoint /v1.0/me/planner/plans doesn't return all my plans

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In the past I was reading a list of plans of current user with this REST call of the beta-API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/plans
```

In July 2017 the planner API was released and there are also some minor changes to the endpoints, so the REST call in the V1.0-API now is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/plans
```

Unfortunately I do not receive all my plans with that endpoint. Apparently I only get plans that exist for a long time, but any newly created plans are not visible. I tried a lot of actions on my plans like subscribing to, assigning tasks to me, favorize the plan in planner hub, making a plan public or private, but nothing helps, new plans remain invisible in the API.

Can anybody explain what the new endpoint exactly does? The [documentation for List plans](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planneruser_list_plans) is not very helpfull.

Can anybody explain how I can a list of all plans (title and id) that I am owner or member of?

The only work-around I have found so far is:

1) Read all unified groups

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a eq 'unified')
```

2) for each group: read the planner plan for that group

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/planner/plans
```

But that would require one request per group, makeing performance horrible on tenants with dozens of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API returns plans that have been shared with the current user. Plans can be shared with a user by adding the user's id to **sharedWith** property of **planDetails** (Edit: currently users do not have permissions to add or remove others from this list). This is a separate set of users from group membership and does not allow access to data for shared users. Instead, the users will have access if they are group members, and lose access if they are removed from the group.

More information and a sample for updating plan details can be found [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannerplandetails_update).

Additionally, you can submit feedback about the API (and other Planner functionality) [here](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/a1a93b69-2f1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: Assuming your answer is correct, then there must be bug in the API because for all new plans, the sharedWith property only contains a single id that is not a valid person, independent of how many persons I share the plan with. For older plans, there are ids of valid users in the sharedWith property, but also new users are not added the sharedWith property.

Comment: Adding members to the group will not update **sharedWith** users. This set is only updated when a user view the plan in Planner, or when people add themselves to it directly.

Comment: we are able to add users to the sharedWith property of the PlanDetails, even with the rights of a normal users as long as the user is member of the group, what is true i n our case. That's the way we do it now.